# Multiple CASE in a SQL QUERY

Tags: android, sql, case

I have a product table with a default price.

TABLE: products

```
id|product|price|
```

I have another table for promotions

TABLE: promotions

```
id|description|
```

And have another table with the prices for promotions

TABLE: prices

```
id|product_id|promotion_id|price|
```

What i am trying to do is:

Get the product, verify if there is price in the prices table with the promotion code "1". If not, verify with promotions code "2", and if still no results, use the fild price from the "products" table.

Now there i can get all the products in one SQL, then for each result search for the price, but i am working with approximately 23 thousand records inside a Android SQLite database and the processing time is not satisfactory.

So, i tried with CASE like this:

```
SELECT product,
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT price FROM price p1 WHERE p1.product_id = prod.id AND p1.promotion_id = 1)
        THEN (SELECT price FROM price p1 WHERE p1.product_id = prod.id AND p1.promotion_id = 1)
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT price FROM price p1 WHERE p1.product_id = prod.id AND p1.promotion_id = 2)
        THEN (SELECT price FROM price p1 WHERE p1.product_id = prod.id AND p1.promotion_id = 2)
        ELSE price
    END,
FROM products prod
```

But, it's still very slow in performance.

Could Someone have another way to get over this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a `LEFT JOIN` and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    prod.product,
    CASE
        WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN pr.promotion_id = 1 THEN pr.price END) IS NOT NULL
            THEN MAX(CASE WHEN pr.promotion_id = 1 THEN pr.price END)
        WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN pr.promotion_id = 2 THEN pr.price END) IS NOT NULL
            THEN MAX(CASE WHEN pr.promotion_id = 2 THEN pr.price END)
        ELSE
            prod.price
    END
FROM products prod
LEFT JOIN price pr
    ON pr.product_id = prod.id
    AND pr.promotion_id IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

the below might work slightly faster by using left join as recommended in another answer. This will return the price in the prices table and also the promotion description just FYI, you can delete that line in the select if you dont need it but it might be handy error-checking.

Additionally, you may have issues when doing more promotions on the same products and wanting to have some sort of historical record of it in the prices/promotions table. Hence why you can comment out the last line which explicitly chooses promotions.id 1 and 2.

The left join onto prices will show the price for the highest prices.id for the product. Ie adding new promotions to the prices/promotions table is possible.

Anyways, this was fun !! Also NB I used the table name prices with an 's'

```
select 
    products.product as `Product Name`, 
    ifnull( case 
                when prices.id is not null 
                    then promotions.description 
            end, "No Promotion") as `Promotion Description`,
    case 
        when prices.id is not null 
            then prices.price 
        else products.price 
    end as `List Price`

from products 
left join prices 
    on products.id=prices.product_id
    and prices.id=(select max(id) from prices where product_id=products.id) -- change max(id) to max(promotion_id) if the latest promos are by the promotions primary key
left join promotions 
    on prices.promotion_id=promotions.id 
    and prices.promotion_id in ('1','2') -- can comment out this line to select the latest promotion based in the join to prices above
    ;
```

Comment: Sorry for not choosing your answer. I like the way that also brought the promotions table, but @felix answered first.

Comment: Don't sweat about it. Just happy to help. Not too worried about right/wrong just yet :P hopefully it worked for you and gave you ideas